# Implementing a PGP Key Server

Tags: pgp

I am fairly new to PGP and crypto in general. Let's say I have around 200 users and they are all going to have a PGP key for email encryption. I want to have a key server that can assign them keys and also have a directory of all of the users public keys so they can get each others. Also, is there anyway since I am producing the private and public key for each user I could then decrypt their emails if I "had" to. By no means do I want to read their emails, but for legal matters I was wondering if it was possible.

How would I go about doing something like this? Thanks

Answer (score 3):

1. I'm not sure you want a server that hosts everyone's private keys. This basically defeats the purpose, since if that server gets compromised then so do their keys, and then goes the data...
2. The keyservers currently in existence allow people to look up people's public keys, but will not assign keys to anyone. The most notable of these keyservers is [SKS](https://bitbucket.org/skskeyserver/sks-keyserver).
3. Yes, if you have the private key, you can decrypt their email/data.